# Titanium App fails to build with deprecation warning

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

App is failing to build on iOS with the following warnings:

[WARN] :   Titanium 7.0.0 deprecates the legacy UI-execution on Kroll-Thread in favor of the Main-Thread.

[WARN] :   The legacy execution will be removed in Titanium SDK 8.0.0.

Here is the environment:

Node.js Version             = 8.9.1

npm Version                 = 5.5.1

CLI Version                 = 5.1.1

SDK Version                 = 7.5.1.GA

Comment: those warnings shouldn't be a problem. Try to run it in debug mode `-l trace` to check if there is an error

Comment: thanks. I was able to get the warnings to go away but now the app hangs after it loads into the simulator on the splash screen. No error messages on the AppC side. When I try to run it on the Xcode, I get the error message "could not find the file ti.main.js"?!